# DOM: with PHP, how to figure out if a node is the last child of it's parent

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to figure out how to know if a node is the last child of another, or not.

I know how to retrieve the parent's `lastChild` name (`$node->parentNode->lastChild->nodeName`), but as sometimes there's many same node names within the same parent, the name is definitly not the way to find the last child.

I'm looking for some kind of iterator which can retrieve the number of childs, and depending of the position of the current node, tell if the current node is the last child.

Thanks!

Comment: Re the PHP tag: This question doesn't relate to PHP, does it? It's client-side DOM, or am I missing the point?

Comment: @T.J.: Which client-side language uses the $-notation for variables like in `$node`? ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK: I assumed it was shorthand. If this is a PHP thing, I'd best disappear. :-) (Edit: Hey, I guess I got lucky, apparently regardless it was a useful answer, since the DOM is the DOM regardless of location.)

Comment: Never mind, your solution works with both the client-side dom and php's DOM extension anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pure DOM terms, if the child is the last child of a parent, its [`nextSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-6AC54C2F) property will be `null`.

Javascript example (not that you're looking for Javascript specifically):

```
if (!child.nextSibling) {
    // It's the last child
}
```

It's important to note that `nextSibling` traverses *nodes*. Sometimes you want to traverse *elements* instead (as opposed to text nodes and such). For instance, in this markup:

```
<p>Testing <span>one</span> two three</p>
```

...the `span` is not the last node in its container (because it's followed by a text node), but it is the last *element* in its container. If you want to look for that, you need a loop checking the `nodeType`, e.g.:

```
// =====
// Note: This example is in JavaScript, but I assume it's easy enough
// to follow what it's doing and translate it to PHP
// =====

// Utility function
function nextElement(node) {
    var rv = node.nextSibling;
    while (rv && rv.nodeType !== 1) {
        rv = rv.nextSibling;
    }
    return rv;
}

// Usage
if (!nextElement(child)) {
    // There was no element after `child`
}
```

Comment: @Bacon: Cool! Sorry if I misread the client-side thing, but at least the DOM is the DOM regardless...

Comment: You could also do _$node === $node->parentNode->lastChild_

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a PHP question, I'll leave a PHP answer (using [DOM](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)) for the posterity:

```
if ($node->isSameNode($node->parentNode->lastChild))
{
    //...
}
```

And if you're using SimpleXML, just convert your node with [dom_import_simplexml()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php).

Comment: sorry for the late coment, but I'd like to thank you for the tips ;)